# Store output file from JMeter Simple Data Writer on Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, azure-load-testing

My jmx script creates an output file from Simple Data Writer Listener after test is executed in JMeter.
I’m running load tests via Azure Pipelines on Azure Load Test service.
Is it possible to save this output file in Azure Pipeline or is there any other alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Publish and download pipeline Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) documentation chapter.

Also be aware that it's possible to control what's being stored into JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) using [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) which are responsible for the [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Answer (score 0):

If you are automating the pipeline via Azure - then you always have an option to download the artifacts for the test conducted.

provide the filename - it will be included to the artifacts - which you can download sooner/later after your test.

For more information: Take a look at the [Azure Load testing Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/tutorial-identify-performance-regression-with-cicd?tabs=pipelines)